# Reading and using elasticsearch metada with logstash configuration

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-configuration

I am having a problem to read a dump file from elasticsearch in another system and push it to my elasticsearch using Logstash via file input plugin. My dump file looks like this:

```
{"_index":"logstash-2018.06.14","_type":"doc","_id":"9Q-9AGQBaaf188t_6DmH","_score":1,"_source":{"offset":124076,"tags":["filebeat_json","beats_input_raw_event","_jsonparsefailure"],...}
{"_index":"logstash-2018.06.14","_type":"doc","_id":"DQ-9AGQBaaf188t_6DqH","_score":1,"_source":{"offset":145573,"tags":["filebeat_json","beats_input_raw_event","_jsonparsefailure"],...}
```

with my configuration file as follow:

```
input{
        file{
                path=> "/home/vm01/Documents/log/output.json"
                type=>"log"
                start_position => "beginning"
                sincedb_path=>"/home/vm01/Documents/sincedb_redefined"
                codec => multiline
                {
                        pattern => '^\{'
                        negate => true
                        what => previous
                }
        }
}

filter{
        if [type] == "log"{
                json{
                        source=>"message"
                }
        } 
}

output{
        if [type] == "log"{
                elasticsearch{
                        hosts=>"localhost:9200"
                        index=>"log-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
                }
        } 
}
```

But it gave me error like this:

`[WARN ] 2018-07-10 13:13:53.685 [Ruby-0-Thread-18@[main]>worker7: /usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:385] elasticsearch - Could not index event to Elasticsearch. {:status=>400, :action=>["index", {:_id=>nil, :_index=>"logstash-2018.07.10", :_type=>"doc", :_routing=>nil}, #<LogStash::Event:0x17052ccb>], :response=>{"index"=>{"_index"=>"logstash-2018.07.10", "_type"=>"doc", "_id"=>"gvflg2QB1n75DXFZzVPL", "status"=>400, "error"=>{"type"=>"mapper_parsing_exception", "reason"=>"Field [_type] is a metadata field and cannot be added inside a document. Use the index API request parameters."}}}}`

I suspect it is because the dump file already contains all metadata of Elasticsearch from previous VMs and it could not be inserted into the new push. Is there a way for me to use the metadata inside the file rather than the one newly created?

Comment: Why not use re-index api or snapshot and restore? You cannot use metadata fields inside the source unless you rename it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should use `elasticdump` for ingesting this es dump file into `elasticsearch`.It will create indices using the metadata present in the input logs or you can even specify the name of the index explicitly.

Link for elasticdump:->
https://www.npmjs.com/package/elasticdump

`elasticdump` is very easy to use and at times proves highly useful.

In the above case I just needed to use the following command(json_stack.log contains the input logs):->

```
elasticdump --input=json_stack.log --output=http://192.168.133.187:9200/
```

This will create indices based on the metadata present in the input log:-^

```
elasticdump --input=json_stack.log --output=http://192.168.133.187:9200/bhavya
```

This will create index with the name `bhavya`:-^

This data can also be ingested using `logstash`, but the simpler and better approach is using `elasticdump`.If you need help installing elasticdump, I'll let you know the steps but try installing it yourself first.